# Окна JOptionPane ломают всю логику моего JFX приложения своим появлением

Tags: java, javafx

В общем примерно так выглядит код:

```
label.setVisible(false);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Типа текст");
```

label естественно из javafx.scene.control

Ну и какого-то чёрта первое условие выполняется только после того, как JOP-окно закроется. ПОЧЕМУ?

К слову, да, я бы мог воспользоваться чем-нибудь менее древним раз уж у меня JFX приложение, но мне лень пилить отдельные окна и условия для них, это намного муторнее...

Comment: `JOptionPane` для `Swing`, в `JavaFX` есть специальные для этого реализации. Используйте их - там можно и не ждать пока окно закроется. Иначе - не надо задавать такие вопросы тут. Лень и программирование не совместимые вещи, увы.

Comment: Я вероятно могу быть не прав, но возможно причина в том что JFX выполняется в своем одном потоке, и не может работать с любыми другими. 
т.е вы получите label.setVisible(false) только после того как закроется JOptionPane.
Кидайте помидорами если смолол чушь )